# In Excel, can you create a conditional statement that applies to every row in an excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm not just trying to highlight a whole row based on one cell's value in that row, I'm trying to apply that conditional statement to every single row.

Do i need to go through the effort to create a conditional statement to all 100 rows? or can I create one that checks what row that value is in, then highlights that particular row accordingly.

I haven't tried VBA, I entered this equation using conditional statement
[image]

Comment: change `'Tests'!$3:$3` to `'Tests'!$3:$103` - it'll apply CF for rows `3:103`

Comment: @simoco You got it! that's an acceptable answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `'Tests'!$3:$3` to `'Tests'!$3:$103` in *"Apply To"* section - it'll apply CF for rows `3:103`.

In that case your formula `=$C3 = "fail"` would be adjusted for each row:

- for row №3: `=$C3 = "fail"`
- for row №4: `=$C4 = "fail"`
- ...
- for row №103: `=$C103 = "fail"`